# Finding Squares on the chessboard attackable by a rook

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, chess

The question is like this..

There is an NxN chessboard. Each square on the chessboard can be either empty or can have a rook. A rook as we know can attack either horizontally or vertically. Given a 2D matrix where 0 represents an empty square and 1 represents a rook, we have to fill in all the cells in the matrix with 1 which represent squares that can be attacked by any rook present on the chessboard.

Now, I could do this easily in O(n^3) time and constant space complexity. And then in O(n^2) time and O(2*n) space complexity. But I need to figure out a solution in O(n^2) time and constant space. Somebody please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that you knew that all your rooks were either in the first column or in the first row. Then you would have a O(n^2) solution with no space overhead by just traversing the first row/column and filling you matrix every time you see a rook (except for filling the first row / first column, that you treat in a last step).
The same holds if all rooks are in the last column / last row, first column / last row, and last column / first row.

Now take your initial matrix and iterate over it until it contains a rook. Let i be the index of the row of this rook and j be the index of its column. Continue iterating over the matrix and for each rook that you find at position (i',j'), remove it replace it with a rook at position (i,j') and another rook at position (i',j).

The matrix you end up with will have ones only along the i-th row and the j-th column. Let A_1 be the submatrix of A formed by its i first rows and 
j first columns. Then A_1 has the property that it contains ones only on its 
last row / las column and thus you can solve for A_1 without space overhead. Do the same for the three other submatrices of A (the one with the n-i+1 last rows and j first colummns, and so on).

If this is not clear please tell me and I will give more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
int main(){
    int n;
    int chess[64][64];
    int hor[64],ver[64];
    //read chessboard
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
            if(chess[i][j] == 1){
                hor[i] = 1;
                ver[j] = 1;
            }
    int cntHor=0;
    int cntVer=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(hor[i] == 1) cntHor++;
        if(ver[i] == 1) cntVer++;
    }
    int result = (cntHor+cntVer)*n-cntHor*cntVer;
    cout<<result;
    return 0
}
```

Comment: You are not supposed to use extra space.

Comment: We can read new value to variable t. I use an array for clarity.